# How to host an WebApp made with ASP.NET core MVC in a local server, but make it online?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

We are developing an ASP.NET core MVC Web Application for a business, and as we're getting close to finish it, there are some questions we have that we couldn't find answers to in here. So hopefully you could help us :)

Well, we already use Amazon RDS free tools for our SQL Server db, but to cut even more costs, the business we're working for asked if we could use one of their spare server machines to host the Application (instead of Elastic Beanstalk for example, or any hosting system). But the problem is, we have very little knowledge in how to configure local/remote servers. This machine we're talking about is already running in a local server here in the building. But how can we make it remote so people can access it from wherever they're, by just typping the url in the browser?

Comment: You (and the business) are not going to want to hear this, but hosting your own services internally if you do not have a firewall / security professional is not going to cut cost.  Recovering from a hack or having data compromised is more expensive than the hosting fees.  Do yourself and the business a favor and don't go this route.

Comment: Use SQL Server on a Private Network is no issue.  If you already have a firewall that allows remote access to your network than no changes are needed.

Comment: @jdweng If the firewall is implemented correctly that is categorically untrue.  Any new application made available through the firewall should require a firewall configuration change.

Comment: If you already inside the private network than you are already through the firewall.

Comment: @squillman We don't have any data that would be sensitive enough to lure hacker, and even if they did hack the application there aren't severe risks for the application health. we just use Sql Server for organization purposes. Even so - is this route possible?

Comment: Possible, but there are so many variations and really depends on how the orgs network is setup plus the ISP.  We can't tell you do xyz and you're all set.  If we assume a minimum of a local network, firewall/router with a connection to the ISP.  Server on local network and you want access externally.  You'd have to configure router/firewall to allow outside traffic to route to the internal server.   Get  the external IP address the ISP assigned to the router/modem.  But then that external address could be dynamic so maybe you'd need get static IP addresses from the ISP which usually cost $.